# Is it possible to use TargetGroupBinding only with VPC Endpoint without NAT in EKS and Fargate configuration?

Tags: amazon-eks, aws-application-load-balancer

I want to build EKS and Fargate using only VPC endpoints without NAT.
However, when I try to apply the TargetGroup Binding, I get the following error.

```
Error from server {Internal}: error when creating "targetgroup-binding.yaml": Internal error occurred: failed calling webhook "mtargetgroupbinding.elbv2.k8s.aws": failed to call webhook: Post "https://aws-load-balancer-webhook-service.kube-system.svc:443/mutate-elbv2-k8s-aws-v1beta-targetgroupbinding?timeout=10s": context deadline exceeded
```

This can be resolved by setting NAT in the private subnet's route table.
Is it possible to solve this without using NAT?

---

EKS was created using CDK.
The control plane is placed in a public subnet and the pods are created in a private subnet.

I want to use ALB to publish web application for API.
And when upgrading Kubernetes, I would like to set up a separate cluster and switch TargetGroups to achieve blue/green deployment.

aws-load-balancer-controller was created according to this document.(https://docs.aws.amazon.com/ja_jp/eks/latest/userguide/aws-load-balancer-controller.html)
`image.repository` `region` `vpcId` are additionally specified because it is a fargate and the pod is a private subnet.

The vpc endpoint was created according to the following document.
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/ja_jp/eks/latest/userguide/private-clusters.html

Here is what I created: `ecr.api` `ecr.dkr` `s3` `elasticloadbalancing` `sts`

Comment: can you explain what you're trying to do? It looks as if you're trying to expose a service using the AWS Load Balancer Controller's TargetGroupBinding CRD. How is your cluster configured? What VPC endpoints have you created? How have you configured the Load Balancer Controller?

Answer (score 0):

After reviewing the vpc endpoint, it started to work.
What I needed was `ecr.api` `ecr.dkr` `s3` `elasticloadbalancing` `sts` `ec2`.